# How to see which host we connected to

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Using RabbitMQ with a cluster of nodes, I set up my factory and connection like this (using the .NET client):

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() 
{ 
    UserName = Properties.Settings.Default.RabbitMQUser,
    Password = Properties.Settings.Default.RabbitMQPassword,
    HostnameSelector = new RandomHostNameSelector(),
    AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true
};
connection = factory.CreateConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.RabbitMQServers.Split(';'));
```

Where `Properties.Settings.Default.RabbitMQServers` is use a semi-colon delimited list of servers:

```
clust01;clust02;clust03
```

After connecting, is there a way to see *which* host it actually picked and is there a way to detect when that might change (because the particular node crashed, was stopped, or rebooted)? `factory.HostName` just returns `localhost`.

**Edit:** It seems `connection.Endpoint.HostName` does give you the actual host name as @Evk and @wally have both stated (thank you). But is there a way to detect a change? It seems that [IConnection](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.6.2/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.6.2-client-htmldoc/html/type-RabbitMQ.Client.IConnection.html) has a `ConnectionShutdown` event which *I guess* might be called as part of switching hosts, but there isn't a corresponding start up or restart event (so I'm assuming it wouldn't know the new host yet). There are also `ConnectionBlocked` and `ConnectionUnblocked` events, but they are undocumented so I have no idea what they do...

Comment: I suppose connection.Endpoint.HostName contains what you want?

Comment: @Evk - You posted as I was typing my own response.  I think you've got the right answer - but I can't test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So how to get host name you already found out, as for how to detect when it changes: when you set `AutomaticRecoveryEnabled` for your factory, `CreateConnection` will really return instance of `AutorecoveringConnection`. This class implements special `IRecoverable` interface, which has event you need. So to detect when automatic recovery happens, subscribe to it like this:

```
var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
((IRecoverable)connection).Recovery += (sender, args) =>
{
    // recovery happened
};
```

Comment: Great stuff - yes that seems to work. Oddly though it seems that it doesn't actually call the selector the first time. It always just connects to the last node in my list of hosts. But when I take that node down it seems it was able to connect to a different node and update the host name.

Comment: @MattBurland Yes, if look at source code it uses HostnameSelector only for regular (non-recoverable) connections. For recoverable it just always chooses the last. You can just implement your own random selection logic maybe, and put preferred hostname last.

Answer (score 1):

I've not got an environment in which I can test this, so it might be completely wrong.

It *looks* like you can use the `endpoint` of the `connection` object (`IConnection`) returned:

```
(string) connection.Endpoint.HostName
```

Cite: https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v1.4.0/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-1.4.0-net-2.0-htmldoc/type-RabbitMQ.Client.IConnection.html

Comment: This is correct for getting the host name, but is there a way to detect if and when it changes?

Comment: I am not aware the RabbitMQ (I've worked with it in PHP and Python, and only very recently C#) "official" libraries perform any such fail-over.

I would expect it to be documented if it does (and I can't see any where I'd expect it to be: https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.6.2/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.6.2-client-htmldoc/html/type-RabbitMQ.Client.IHostnameSelector.html)